# Adobe Air on ios load hosted swf contains code

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

Is there still no way to load external swf that contains actionscript on ios?
i keep getting that uncompiled actionscript when testing the app on ipad
i have read many old questions and i am wondering if it is fixed or not
Thanks

Comment: Longer answer: No, loading and running JIT'd of code at runtime violates Apple security policy and is not allowed and thus Adobe's AIR runtime actively prevents it on iOS.

Comment: thanks, u saved me alot of time

Comment: You should read this post, it explain how you can load external swf containing ABC code http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2013/03/08/external-hosting-of-secondary-swfs-for-air-apps-on-ios/

Comment: thanks for your help